# How to select rows based on specific conditions of a range of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose, I have the following dataframe:

```
A B C D E F
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0.9 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 -1.95 0
0 0 0 0 2.75 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to select rows which have only zeros or ones based on the columns `C, D, E and F`. For this example, the expected output is

```
 A B C D E F
 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

**How can I do this with considering a range of columns in pandas?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df[['C','D','E','F']].isin([1,0]).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: How can I do this with a specific range of columns?

Comment: @orbit what do you mean? You can define `specific_range_of_columns` as a what-ever-you-want list (`specific_range_of_columns = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']` for example) and then `df[specific_range_of_columns]` instead of `df[['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]` inside the `loc`.